# Why intensity can be independently multiplied in case of considering both both single slit and double slit interference combined pattern?

Tags: optics, waves, interference

http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide14.pdf  in this pdf the author said that intensity will be just multiplication of both independent intensity patterns , they didnt mention a proof or a reason as why in 14.7 section , is it possible to show why its independently can be multiplied for getting resultant intensity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this double slit, with distance $D$ between the two slits,
each with slit width $a$.

[image: double slit]
<sub>(image from [Antonine education](http://www.antonine-education.co.uk/pages/Physics_2/Waves/WAV_08/diffraction_grating_formula.htm), slightly adapted by me)</sub>

The light amplitude $E(\theta)$ into direction $\theta$ can be calculated
straight-forward according to Huygens' principle by summing the contributions

- of the lower slit ($x$ from $-\frac{D}{2}-\frac{a}{2}$ to $-\frac{D}{2}+\frac{a}{2}$ and
- of the upper slit ($x$ from $+\frac{D}{2}-\frac{a}{2}$ to $+\frac{D}{2}+\frac{a}{2}$

The path difference of each contributing ray (compared to the path length of
an imaginary ray originating from the center between the slits) is $x\sin\theta$.
And hence its phase is $kx\sin\theta$ (with $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$).

Summing these contributions you get
$$\begin{align}
E(\theta)
&= E_0 \left(
     \int_{-\frac{D}{2}-\frac{a}{2}}^{-\frac{D}{2}+\frac{a}{2}}
   + \int_{+\frac{D}{2}-\frac{a}{2}}^{+\frac{D}{2}+\frac{a}{2}}
   \right) e^{ikx\sin\theta}\ \text{d}x \\
&= E_0 \left(
     e^{-i\frac{kD}{2}\sin\theta}
 +e^{+i\frac{kD}{2}\sin\theta}
 \right)
 \int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{+\frac{a}{2}}e^{ikx\sin\theta}\ \text{d}x \\
&= E_0 
  \left(2\cos\left(\frac{kD}{2}\sin\theta\right)\right)
  \left(a\frac{\sin\left(\frac{ka}{2}\sin\theta\right)}{\frac{ka}{2}\sin\theta} \right)
\end{align}$$

And finally you get the intensity by taking the absolute square of this
amplitude $E(\theta)$ (using $I_0=4E_0^2a^2$ as an abbreviation):
$$I(\theta)=I_0
  \left(\cos\left(\frac{kD}{2}\sin\theta\right)\right)^2
  \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{ka}{2}\sin\theta\right)}{\frac{ka}{2}\sin\theta}\right)^2
$$
Here you have the two factors:
the left factor describing the double slit pattern (with distance $D$),
and the right factor describing the single slit pattern (with width $a$).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir , this answer is very much helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) for Fourier transforms.  The double slit transmission function is a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of  a single wide slit and two narrow slits. So, in the [Fraunhoffer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction), the combined image amplitude is the product of the Fourier transform of the single wide slit ($\propto (\sin \Lambda x)/x$ and the two narrow slits
($\propto \cos kx$).

Comment: Thanks Sir for telling :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole text of the chapter is based on "classical" mechanics and there are some critical assumptions. In the classical process the EM field can simply cancel but as photons do contain energy this is really a violation of conservation of energy.  For the classical mechanics to work the Huygens assumption must also be made ( that a wave is broken into individual sources spaced exactly a wavelength apart).

In reality "interference" even works with photons fired one at a time... as Dirac, Feynman and many others say, " each photon determines its own path".  The Feynman path integral is a more advanced approach to the DSE.

The multiplication step is based purely on insight and that the required outcome fits the pattern seen .... there is no derivation for it.

Comment: Sir i asked for reason of multiplication not about what is happening here with photons , that i already got from your previous comment :)